# Elasticsearch searching for events with multiple date types

Tags: events, elasticsearch

I am searching events in ElasticSearch. Each event can have a specific start date set (in seconds) or the event is on-going till it is canceled manually. In my search query I am searching (among other parameters) with today's date and would like to find all events that:

- start today (date > today AND dateType = specific)
- OR are on-going (dateType = on-going)

My query looks like this, but it doesn't work:

```
"query":{  
  "bool":{  
      "must":[  
        {  
            "range":{  
              "latitude":{  
                  "gte":45.78560033657945,
                  "lte":46.54954406342055
              }
            }
        },
        {  
            "range":{  
              "longitude":{  
                  "gte":13.75487411320551,
                  "lte":14.857968686794491
              }
            }
        },
        {  
            "multi_match":{  
              "query":"tes",
              "type":"phrase_prefix",
              "fields":[  
                  "title^3",
                  "subtitle^2"
              ]
            }
        }
      ],
      "should":[  
        {  
            "range":{  
              "validDateUnix":{  
                  "gte":1487026800000
              }
            }
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on your `should` part in order to capture both constraints, right now you've only capture half the first constraint. Try this:

```
"query":{  
  "bool":{  
      "must":[  
        {  
            "range":{  
              "latitude":{  
                  "gte":45.78560033657945,
                  "lte":46.54954406342055
              }
            }
        },
        {  
            "range":{  
              "longitude":{  
                  "gte":13.75487411320551,
                  "lte":14.857968686794491
              }
            }
        },
        {  
            "multi_match":{  
              "query":"tes",
              "type":"phrase_prefix",
              "fields":[  
                  "title^3",
                  "subtitle^2"
              ]
            }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should":[  
        {  
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                   "dateType": "specific"
                }
              },
              {
                "range":{  
                   "validDateUnix":{  
                      "gte":1487026800000
                   }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
           "term": {
              "dateType": "on-going"
           }
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to work. The result contains past events. So the range filter is letting them trough somehow.

Comment: The first part is now working correctly and I am able to filter only new events but the on-going are not included.

Comment: Can you show a sample document that should match the on-going constraint?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "id": "7812c801-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "title": "Know Your Student Protest Rights",
  "subtitle": "Know what you can and can't do. Join our campus communities to help other students understand their rights. Peer to peer advocacy is critical to our approach.",
  "whatIsImpact": "The ACLU makes sure that our basic Constitutional rights – to free speech, to privacy, to be innocent until proven guilty – don’t just exist on paper, but also practice. The ACLU enforces the vision that these freedoms be guaranteed to every person in this country. These are our American values.",
  "whatIsNeeded": "Our goal is to connect with young Americans so they understand their civic rights.",
  "whyIsNeeded": "The ACLU of Northern California is an enduring guardian of justice, fairness, equality, and freedom, working to protect and advance civil liberties for all Californians. This includes students!",
  "url": "https://www.aclunc.org",
  "address": "Ljubljana, Slovenia",
  "dateType": "on-going",
  "issues": [],
  "latitude": "46.1671294",
  "longitude": "14.3058337",
  "organization": "68c9c701-0000-0000-98c9-c70100000000",
  "organizationName": "Developer test",
  "type": "Volunteer"
}
```

Comment: @Val here is the sample document that should match on the on-going condition.